# Rewriting to subdirectory and then to React's index.html using root .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I am trying to create .htaccess file that will be located in the root webserver directory. In the root, there will be also directories named backend/ and frontend/ + few more (their names are variable).

Current tree may look like this:

```
/
  .htaccess
  frontend/
      static/
      index.html
      manifest.json
  backend/
      files/
      index.php
  other/
```

Since the front-end (React) and back-end (PHP) is done by others and is deployed using CI, I don't have any control over the files and folders in that two directories.

What I am trying to accomplish with the .htaccess file is to:

1. rewrite (not redirect) everything that goes to `/**` and does not exist itself to `/frontend/**`
2. everything in `/frontend/**` that does not exists should return `/frontend/index.html`

Here are some examples:

- `/` becomes `/frontend/` (#1)
- `/index.html` becomes `/frontend/index.html` (#1)
- `/manifest.json` becomes `/frontend/manifest.json` (#1)
- `/static/script.js` becomes `/frontend/static/script.js` (#1)
- `/module` becomes `/frontend/index.html` (#1 and #2)
- `/backend/**` will not be rewritten as the directory exists
- `/other/**` will not be rewritten as the directory exists

My current file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /

   # Rewrite root directory to frontend
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/index.html [NC,L,QSA]

   # Rewrite non-existent files and folders to frontend
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

which mainly fails to rewrite `/module` to `/frontend/index.html`.
How should I continue?

Comment: what about just adding a ErrorDocument 404 that redirects to /frontend/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# skip backend/ and other/ directories
RewriteRule ^(?:backend|other)/ - [L,NC]

# forward these known paths to /frontend/
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)$ /frontend/$1 [L,NC]

# rewrite an alphanumeric URI that is non-file/dir to /frontend/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+/?$ /frontend/index.html [L]

# Rewrite non-existent files and folders to frontend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I don't know the names of modules beforehand ("module" was just an example), nor I know the names of files in frontend directory (they are generated dynamically by React's NPM).

Comment: I thought of it too, but the issue is that `frontend/` is deployed with CI that overwrites everything inside. I can only use the `.htaccess` that is placed in the root directory.

Comment: This still assumes I know that `manifest.json` and `static/scripts.js` will be present. The front-end, as it is deployed by CI is a black-box for me. Also, it does not rewrite the submodules (`module/` or `module2/` and so on) to `index.html` where the React app resides.

Comment: See updated. It does rewrite `moduleN/` or `/static/script\.js` etc because that is not a file or directory found in site root hence it will be handled by last rule that rewrites to `/frontend/moduleN`.

Comment: Thanks! I see it satisfies the #1 - it get rewritten to `frontend/`. However, the #2 does not work. I need the modules (it's name can be anything alpha-numeric) to be rewritten to `index.html` (resp. `frontend/index.html`) where the React app resides.